# Char массив в byte массив с++

Tags: массивы, char, файлы, java, c++

Есть клиент на java, с него на сервер c++ отсылается wav файл.

Как правильно записать полученные данные в файл, если сервер принимает значения в массив char. Если записать его, то размер файла будет меньше размера принятых данных в 50 раз, если массив записать посимвольно, то в wav будет только шум, зато если отослать этот char обратно клиенту и там записать, то все нормально.

Как char перевести в byte или как записать char, чтобы все нормально проигрывалось?

Comment: показывайте, как записываете. Думаю, что в первом случае, Вы просто записываете размер. Или неправильно пишите (ну не может он быть просто так в 50 раз меньше).

Comment: Мне кажется, этот вопрос не имеет ответа потому, что вопрос на самом деле по Java, но соответствующий тэг не указан.

Comment: Предположу, что автор пытается записать массив в файл как обычную строку, забыв о том, что в массиве могут быть нулевые байты.

Comment: А полученная строка содержит абсолютно любые символы, в том числе и непечатаемые, или представляет собой закодированные бинарные данные, например Base64 или какой-нибудь Uuencode?